# Adding a friend back into a Facebook group who has previously left

Tags: facebook-groups

A friend left a Facebook group and now he wants to rejoin the group.

When I try to add him, Facebook tells me that "Mr.X has already left the group".

How do I add him back in again?

Comment: how does the group member send a 2nd request??? :S

Comment: If you make the group closed, will everyone see it in the news status or only when you enter the name of the group?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to ask the friend to request an invite back into the group. Once they leave, they burn the invitation from the first attempt and you can no longer add the same person.

> #### [My friend left my group. How can I send a second invitation?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=18896)
>
> Unfortunately, you will not be able to send a second group invitation to the same friend. The person will have to request to join the group again.

This probably relates to people who were added to groups they didn't want to be a part of and left. This prevents them from being added again to groups they don't want to join unless they explicitly request it.

Comment: But how does the person request it ... as it is a secret group and not visible from his account after he left. Now that he has left and want to rejoin he seems to have stuck. Where does he have to go to request a reinvite?

Comment: Can you make it public for a short period of time and then back to secret? @exp

Comment: Not possible , because facebook has withdrawn the "Edit group" button :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a member back if he has left the group before.

Just change your group setting to "closed" so your ex-member can see the group again and let her/him request to rejoin the group again. Admin should accept her, then you can change the group setting back to secret again.

Answer (score 1):

The admin/owner the group (if closed or secret) on the settings has to check "Only administrators can confirm the candidate requests". You can then make a new request to the membership group. And when you're in there, then the owner of the group can again make it secret or closed.

Comment: Can you please ensure that all future posts are in English. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the URL in the address bar and send it to your friend. They can then invite themselves once they go to the website -

example: www.facebook.com/groups/mygroup

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete answer as of April 2012:

1. As the group administrator, go to the group page.
2. From the group page, click the gear icon in the upper right corner (next to the search icon).  This should drop down a menu; choose "Edit Group".
3. Change the group privacy setting from "Secret" to "Closed" and save the settings. (Note: this will notify everyone in the group that you are doing this, so you may want to warn them)
4. Send the url for the group (e.g. http://www.facebook.com/groups/123456789012345/) to the user you want to add.
5. Have that user click the url and add themselves to the group.
6. Accept their request
7. Switch the group back to "Secret"